# How can i upload my tempates to concrete5?

Tags: content-management-system, concrete5

I am using c5 for social networking of my members. For front page i have my own templates in which all my css/images/javascript files are involved.How can i upload my template and change the theme.I just want to use my theme.How can i connect all this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a theme. In your root/themes/, create a folder and name it basically whatever you want, as long as it's not the same as the name of one of the other themes. in that folder, create a default.php and view.php, as well as an "elements" folder where you can store your theme's header.php and footer.php, examples of which can be found in your root/concrete/themes/greensalad.

You could just copy that greensalad folder from root/concrete/themes/ to root/themes/, then change the name of the folder to a unique name for your custom theme -- root/themes/my_custom_theme, for example. After that, modify the new folder's contents however you want to. that's what i would do.

once you've created a theme that includes the required default.php and view.php, as well as your header.php and footer.php, you can create folders inside root/themes/my_custom_theme to store your root/themes/my_custom_theme/js, root/themes/my_custom_theme/css, root/themes/my_custom_theme/images, etc.

Lastly, you have to install your new theme. You can do that on your dashboard at yoursite.com/dashboard/pages/themes/, or, if you don't have pretty urls enabled, yoursite.com/index.php/dashboard/pages/themes/.

After that you should see your custom theme there, at yoursite.com/dashboard/pages/themes/, under "installed themes."

you can grab your .js files from your root/themes/my_custom_theme/js/, and your .css files from your root/themes/my_custom_theme/css/, by including something like the following in your custom theme's header.php, footer.php or default.php.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php  echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/css/my_custom_style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php  echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/js/my_custom_script.js"></script>
```